Trying to run opensearch and opensearch Dashboard but facing login issue
I am trying to run opensearch and opensearch Dashboard on local using docker
but i am facing login issue in opensource dashboard
"Invalid username or password. Please try again."
i am using default creds, i have also disabled security plugin but still same issue
can someone please help, i am new to 'opensearch'
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.9.0
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - plugins.security.disabled=true
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - opensearch_net

  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.9.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    environment:
      - OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://opensearch:9200"]
      - server.host="0.0.0.0"
      - DASHBOARDS_INDEX=.opensearch_dashboards
      - OPENSEARCH_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - opensearch
    networks:
      - opensearch_net

networks:
  default:
    name: kafka-net
    driver: bridge
  monitoring:
    driver: bridge
  opensearch_net:
    driver: bridge


tried disabling security plugin
tried default creds

